# PayPal button not working correctly, am I missing something?

Tags: html, paypal

Basically I require some help, I've managed to come up with a online quote script that works as intended.

However the problem is when coming to take payments. 
I thought it would be easy to simply add a PayPal buy now button. However that doesn't seem to be the case as my button isn't working.

I didn't know if anyone would be able to shed some light on my situation?

You can view the PayPal button here
http://www.ncrprintinguk.co.uk/  <-- Scroll down to Order now.

The code is;

```
<label class="checkbox inline"></label>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="VQC7SQN2J3TXA">
<input id="output">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> </form>
```

Thanks in advance
Adam

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm no expert for this, but for those who may be able to help you, it would be helpful to be more specific about what "isn't working" actually means. Any error messages? What behaviour do you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: Thanks Rene, Nothing happens it just reloads the page. I believe Dima V may have found where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On the page itself you're missing the post action & method attributes

Comment: Brilliant, I thought there was something I missed. I'll give it a quick Google and I'll get back to you once I've researched into it. Thanks again

Comment: Would  "<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">" Not be the Post & Method attributes?

Comment: They are, but you haven't added them on the website you've provided a URL to. it's just <form> at http://www.ncrprintinguk.co.uk/
The code you provided here is fine, but on the actual website you are missing these.